# What if I push git commit to remote if other, later commits exists?

Tags: git, github

I have a simple GIT local repository (only master) downloaded from gitHub. I work with another programmer on the same repo.

Through the month I added a over a dozen commits to remote on gitHub.
Now he pushed 2 commits. One is actual but second, which was created a month ago but not pushed to remote.
I see there are a problem with this actual commit because it was mixed with my earlier commits. That mean gitHub shows diffs from the other (earlier) commits.

Have you ever met with such a thing?

Comment: "such a thing" is the very reason git and other VCS exist. The general principle to handle this is : before you push on a given branch, you must be up-to-date with its current state by pulling beforehand. If conflicts arise at this point, you resolve them on your own local branch, then push the updated result.

Comment: @RomainVALERI ok, I understand that, I always do as You wrote. But what's now! I cant link repo because its private.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to push your local code to the remote repository. And you don't want to take pull of the code which is two commits ahead  and merge the remote repo commits with your local code base. In such case you can forcefully push your code to remote.

```
git push -f origin master
```

This will **replace** the remote code with your local history, so be careful.